# Can I assign an "alias" to a repository URL in mercurial/kiln?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I keep all my personal projects on my Kiln account and I also have a bitbucket account where I push repositories when I need to share them with people.  Is there some way for me to setup an alias for a repo URL so I can do something like

```
hg push kiln
```

or

```
hg push bitbucket
```

instead of typing in the entire URL each time:
 `hg push https://path/to/repo`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in your repo's hgrc file using the [paths section](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#paths).

```
[paths]
default = https://path/to/repo
kiln = https://path/to/kiln
bitbucket = https://path/to/bitbucket
```

If you create new repos often, you can also add this to your ~/.hgrc file.