# Giving names to URLs in hg?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I've used Git for quite some time now, and I'm used to adding remotes to my repository, so I can push and pull from URLs with a particular name. Is it possible to do the same in hg? I'm tired of typing the full URL every time I want to push.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I assign an "alias" to a repository URL in mercurial/kiln?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944411/can-i-assign-an-alias-to-a-repository-url-in-mercurial-kiln)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> These URLs can all be stored in your configuration file with path
>   aliases under the [paths] section like so:
>
> ```
> [paths]
> alias1 = URL1
> alias2 = URL2
> ...
> ```
>
> You can then use the alias for
>   any command that uses a URL (for example `hg pull alias1` will be
>   treated as `hg pull URL1`).

http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#url-paths

There's also [SchemesExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SchemesExtension) if you do a lot of work with various repos on a particular site (e.g. Bitbucket).

Comment: It should also be said that if you have a path named `default`, hg will use that when you run `hg push` or `hg pull` with no alias.